# How to hide line chart data lables, stacked at left side for moving linechart?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, livecharts

I am using livechart https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

I need to use a moving linechart. Everything is ok. But the datalabels are stacked
at the left side.

[image]

Comment: This is a bug, will move this to https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/297 thanks

Comment: A workaround for now is remove all the points as soon as they are not visible in the axis range (7:00PM-3:00AM)

Comment: First thanks for the reply. But I am using a chart that is also scrollable. By changing the axis value it is easy to implement the scrollable chart using your library. But only problem is that the chart values before 7 pm is still showing on left side. If I remove the points, then the implementation for scrollable chart will be difficult. However your library is so good and easy to customize.

Comment: I will fix it asap, thanks for the feed back

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It will be great help for me.